# Populate select menu from PHP/MySQL using javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have this code:

```
<script>
var values = <?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM billing_sagenominalcodes order by code ASC";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$nominalcodes = array();
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    $nominalcodes[] = $result['code'];
}
echo json_encode($nominalcodes);
?>;
</script>

<select name="sagenominalcode" id="sagenominalcode">
<script>addOptions(document.getElementById('sagenominalcode'), values);</script>
</select>
```

it works exactly how i need it to but i am wondering if it is possible to display the column name "name" from the database in the select options as well as the code?

for example rather than just

123

to have it like this

123 - name

Comment: Please consider using **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead of `mysql_*` type functions, as they have been deprecated as of version 5.5

Comment: i will do - this is just what i have at the moment - any ideas on it?

Comment: I don't know what the Js function `addOptions` does but it seems like if you augment this line  `$nominalcodes[] = $result['code'] . ' - ' . $result['name'];` you will be closer to your desired result.

Comment: This could also work. `addOptions` could do a `.split()` on the string ` - ` to retrieve both values.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to rigidly separate your php and your js. The way the code is written will work as is, but is *very* brittle, and can break catastrophically, leading to [action-at-a-distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_%28computer_science%29) style bugs.

For example, if your database schema were refactored to remove the `code` column, then your javascript would be rendered broken, with a cause that nobody would suspect.

---

That said, if you'd like to also display the data in the `name` column in the select options, you'll have to pass that data into `$nominalcodes` as well. Right now, it contains an indexed array of data (perhaps an `int` or a `string`), but you'll want to change that so it contains an indexed array of arrays.

So, before:

```
$nominalcodes = array(1,3,5,78,3,2,234);
```

and after:

```
$nominalcodes = array(
    array(1, 'foobar'),
    array(3, 'larry'),
    array(5, 'bob'),
    ...
);
```

At this point, you'll have to refactor your javascript `addOptions` function so that it can properly parse an array of arrays, instead of an array of single values.